# What all is different about the map in the Capture the Flag game mode?

Tags: overwatch

The new event added a new game mode: "Capture the Rooster" (Flag). It's played on Lijiang Tower, almost. What is different about this instance of the map?

Comment: I think there are quite a few differences, most notably the placement of mega health packs, map design, the spawn rooms, etc. I do not know of every change though.

Comment: I wonder if this question should be updated to include the other CTF maps?

Answer (score 7):

There are a handful of differences:

- Players start in a new location. In regular Lijang Tower, you always start in an Overwatch airplane/shuttle. In the CtR mode, you start in a decorated spawn room inside an actual building. Other than this, there is no difference to the actual layout of the map.
- The map itself is decorated with various Chinese New year decorations, such as paper lanterns and festive streamers. These are "eye candy" and do not have any impact on the game.
- As far as I can tell, health packs still spawn in the same locations as the regular map.
- There is a flag point near either team's spawn. The flag must be captured and transported back to your own base to score points.
- Obviously the normal control points are nonexistant in this mode.

Comment: It's worth noting that there appear to be more mega-health packs lying around, and some of the geometry/map layouts have been changed.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I'm not sure about that. I think all the mega-health packs in CtR are also mega-health packs in the regular mode. You're probably just noticing them more now since side passages are more used in this game mode than in a regular game. There do seem to be some minor layout changes right outside spawn to make room for the flag, but the main parts of the map are all the same (side passages included).

Comment: Parts of "Night Market" feel smaller, or like the walls have changed in some places, especially in the area across from where the control point would typically be. I'll see if I can test it out tonight to see if there are some differences.

Comment: The two health packs in the Control Center map that are in the room used as the flag room for this mode seem to be absent. I've died a couple of times running to that corner only to find sadness and death.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Night Market doesn't normally have moving platforms that act as lifts.

Which is a layout change.